# how to get the width of a string in a specific font?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, django

I am doing question/answer tests in my Django app and to give a hint of the sought answer to the users I want the input field to have the same `width` as the expected answer string will take.

Currently what I am doing is :

- backend, shuffling the answer :

  ```
  width = ''.join(random.sample(answer,len(answer)))
  ```
- frontend, when my ajax request suceeds :

  ```
  $('#inputNotDisplayed').text(data.width);
  // put the answer string in a hidden div that has
  // the same css characteristics as my answer receiver input (font-size, font-family...)
  $('#answerInput').width($('#inputNotDisplayed').width()).focus();
  // give its width to the visible input that is meant to received the answer
  // and give the focus to the input
  $('#inputNotDisplayed').remove();
  ```

it works nicely but it has one main flaw : you can quite easily get the shuffled string by checking the data received.

another option I see is that when Q and A data is stored in the db I could calculate the width of the answer in order to yield it when a question is asked but then what if I change the font I want to use or its size ?

is there a way to know the width of every character size for a specific font and can it be used backend ? Any other idea ?

Also, I am not using a monospaced font and I don't want to ;).

Comment: Would it not be easier to use stars or another symbol to represent how many characters there are?

Comment: For many reasons, you can't reliably pre-calculate the pixel width of a string. Why are you afraid of your users peeking in your JavaScript / XHR? Is that somehow sensitive data? (Doesn't seem like it is)

Comment: @StaceyBurns, it would be easier for sure but for some design reason it is not an option.

Comment: @amit, data are not sensitive but still I don't find that method elegant even though it works.

Comment: Personally I don't see that as an issue at all, and again, it's the *only* reliable method... (Other then going through hoops in the sky, measuring each letter combination and calculating)

Comment: yes but you don't return the width, you return an anagram. If you want to return the width then just return `len(answer)`

Comment: @Sayse len(answer) give me the number of chars, but all the chars do not have the same width so i can't deduce the width of a string from its length, i can only from the word itself or an anagram

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now. Still either need to decipher the width of the string on the backend preferably. The only other thing I could really think of is to find the width on a control that you create/remove in a minified version of your js

Comment: Just realised that's what you already are doing... I've deleted my answer but the original jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mox7eLx9/) if you still wished to see it.

Comment: There is no simple, backend-only solution for that because length of characters will depend on user browser, operating system and if he have any font anti-aliasing turned on in system (and which one).

Comment: @GwynBleidD, fair enough, I guess I will just keep the work around I am using right now then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to send anagram to user, you can use monotype font or at least font that have only some lengths of characters used (for example font in which all slim letters will have same width, all medium letters will have same width and all wide letters will same exact width). After doing that, you can replace some characters in random string with equivalent wiidth characters.

Comment: I edited the answer with your comment because it made be understand why I couldn't do it backend end, if you know some of the font that are not monospaced but use few different length as mentioned in your answer, can you please add them to the answer ? thanks